# Run multiple commands, but run the last one in the background

Tags: bash, shell, posix

I have 4 commands I want to run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db && \
sudo chmod 755 /data/db && \
sudo chown -R addison.pan: /data && \
mongod &
```

I only want to run mongod in the background if the other 3 above it succeed.  But when I type this into bash, it runs the whole thing as one background task.  How do I only make the `mongod` run in the background, and only if it gets to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To run one or more commands in a separate process, enclose that series of commands in parentheses. As specified in the Single Unix Specification, [§2.9.4 “Compound Commands”](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04):

> `( compound-list )`
>
> Execute *compound-list* in a subshell environment […]

To group one or more commands in the *same* shell process, enclose that series of commands in curly braces:

> `{ compound-list ; }`
>
> Execute *compound-list* in the current process environment. […]

That's true for any POSIX shell (so it [also works in Bash](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Grouping)).

So your example can be changed to:

```shell
sudo mkdir -p /data/db && \
sudo chmod 755 /data/db && \
sudo chown -R addison.pan: /data && \
( mongod & )
```

That may be good because you want the `mongod` process separated. On the other hand, a more general answer would be to group the list of commands *within* the same shell process:

```shell
sudo mkdir -p /data/db && \
sudo chmod 755 /data/db && \
sudo chown -R addison.pan: /data && \
{ mongod & }
```

Both these are described in the above documentation references.

Comment: True, but inefficient to leverage unnecessarily: You're forking an extra time for the subshell. `{ mongod & }` would avoid the overhead. Sometimes that extra fork is actually desired (when you don't want a direct child-process relationship), but those tend to be corner cases.

Comment: We don't need the backslashes when we have those trailing `&&`'s, right?

Answer (score 2):

Be explicit.  There's no need to try to abuse the syntax to use a short-circuit:

```
if \
    sudo mkdir -p /data/db \
    && sudo chmod 755 /data/db \
    && sudo chown -R addison.pan: /data
then
    mongod & 
fi
```

Comment: If we put `&&` at the end, then we can eliminate the backslashes on lines 2 and 3 and make the code more readable too.

Comment: @codeforester, I used to think that ending lines with && was more readable, but have since changed my opinion.  To the reader, it is more clear that the line is continued with the '&&' at the start.  A semi-reasonable compromise is to end with '&&' and indent the continuation line.  YMMV.  coding styles change, hairstyles change, interest rates fluctuate...

Answer (score 0):

Use parens:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db && \
sudo chmod 755 /data/db && \
sudo chown -R addison.pan: /data && \
(mongod &)
```

Comment: There's performance cost to this -- parens create a subshell, meaning an extra fork before the one for the background process. Curly braces (as in `{ mongod & }`) are cheaper, being *only* grouping without subshell creation. (Admittedly, they're a little harder to use: If you weren't backgrounding it with `&`, you'd need a `;` to prevent the `}` from being parsed as an argument to pass to `mongod`).

Answer (score 0):

You could run multiple commands within `sudo`, for example:

```
sudo sh -c 'mkdir -p /data/db && chmod 755 /data/db && chown -R <user>: /data' \
&& mongod &
```